# How to get a date string of 3 day3 ago or a day ago by current day of week in Jenkins pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins

I want to get a last date of weekday, like today-3 if today is Monday or today-1, in Jenkins pipeline script.
So I wrote a script like this :

```
environment {
    TODAY_WEEK = "`date +%u`"    // today is 9/26/2022, so "1"
    LAST = "${env.TODAY_WEEK == "1" ? "`date -d '-3 day' +%Y%m%d`" : "`date -d '-1 day' +%Y%m%d`"}"
}
...
    sh( "diff report_${LAST}.json report_${TODAY}.json" )
```

But when I run this script, `LAST` always become `date -d '-1 day'` regardless current date.
So I tried to another method :

```
environment {
    TODAY_WEEK = "`date +%u`"    // today is 9/26/2022, so "1"
    LAST = getLastDate(env.TODAY_WEEK)
}
...
def getLastDate(dayOfWeek) {
    today = new Date()
    if (dayOfWeek.equals("1")) {
        last = today - 3
    } else {
        last = today - 1
    }
    return last.format("yyyyMMdd")
}
```

But I got same result - LAST become always date of 'today - 1'.
What's wrong with this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pipeline script will help:

```java
pipeline {
    agent any
     
    environment {
        TODAY_WEEK = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'date +%u')
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Run'){
            steps {
                 script {
                     today = new Date()
                     if (env.TODAY_WEEK.toInteger() == 1) {
                        testLast = today - 3
                        lastDayofWeek = testLast.format("yyyyMMdd")
                        echo "${lastDayofWeek}"
                     }
                     else {
                        testLast = today - 1
                        lastDayofWeek = testLast.format("yyyyMMdd")
                        echo "${lastDayofWeek}"
                    }
                }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Output:

[image]

---

**Reason of not correct output of your job**

In your pipeline script, the environment variable `TODAY_WEEK` is not returning any result and thus the script always fail to invoke the **else** condition.

You can print the environment variables in Jenkins pipeline using the below:

```bash
sh "printenv"
```